# Type mismatch: inferred type is T but kotlin.Any was expected

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
val map = HashMap<Int, Any>()
fun <T> test(t: T) = map.put(0, t) // Type mismatch: inferred type is T but kotlin.Any was expected
```

But [every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/), so why this error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`T` is nullable in this function. You should explicitly specify that it's non-nullable.

```
fun <T : Any> test(t: T) = map.put(0, t)
```

Comment: To add to that, the default bound for a naked `<T>` is `Any?`